# How to find the top 10% values based on groups of one column in Excel?

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I have a table with two columns - Region and Sales. I wish to create an indicator variable that shows True when the corresponding record lies in the top 10% of that group else false.

I could think of a process in which I first find the rank of each record in each group after which I go about assigning the indicator based on the ranks, e.g. if there are 20 records for one group then True will be assigned for only ranks one and two.

Here's the formula for the rank that I chose; `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$6:$B$113=B7) * (C7<$C$6:$C$113))+1`

[image]

Comment: What result do you expect? Can you show? Also post data as text table so that we can copy.

Comment: @Harun24hr in case it helps I found this new excel feature: [Insert data from picture](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-data-from-picture-3c1bb58d-2c59-4bc0-b04a-a671a6868fd7). There are also some free similar tools online. I discovered it today. It is very handy in such situations. Anyway the person who posts the question should help too.

Comment: What is the role of column D in  the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

***D6***

```
=COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$113,B6,$C$6:$C$113,">"&C6)<=ROUND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$113,B6)*0.1,0)
```

in 365 dinamically

```
=COUNTIFS($B$6:$B$113,B6:B113,$C$6:$C$113,">"&C6:C113)<=ROUND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$113,B6:B113)*0.1,0)
```